vscode it's highlighting all tags instead of opening and closing tags
when i click in a tag, my vscode highlights all the tags with the same name, but i want it to highlight only the matching tag. it used to do this normally, but one day it somehow changed and i don't know how to normalize
here's a screenshot of how it's working now, i clicked the div at line 11 and it's supposed to highlight the closing div tag at line 23, not all divs
[all tags highlighted instead of only the closing tag]
(https://i.sstatic.net/rUavw9Xk.png)
i tried editing my settings by typing "editor.occurrencesHighlight", but i can only select "off", "singleFile" or "multiFile" (the "off" option doesn't highligh any of the tags and i already tried "true" or "false" but it doesn't accept, only those 3 options).
also installed the highlight matching tag extension, but it's ugly and i don't want to use an extension for this

this is probably word highlighting, but I can't understand why it's doing this. that or you've changed something about linked editing range highlighting.

This is happening to me with a fresh install of vscode and also the insiders version. In my case i don't work with pure html files, but  .svelte files, and its extension has this problem. If i select HTML  as the language for any .svelte file, the matching tags are properly highlighted.

as far as I know, Visual Studio Code does not have this feature built in. But I solved this problem with this plugin: VSCode Highlight Matching Tag
Extension
Here's how it works, I recommend you use it:

Thanks...
